# How do I link this execlp program using ld in Windows?

Tags: assembly, mingw, gnu-assembler, shellcode

I'm using gas from MinGW (gcc, as, and ld to be specific) to compile the following to-be shellcode in Windows...

```
    .text
    .globl _main
    .def   _main; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef
    #.extern _execlp
    .def   _execlp; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef
_main:
    push  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    pushl $0
    pushl $0x00657865
    pushl $0x2e646d63
    call  _execlp
    movl  %ebp, %esp
    pop   %ebp
```

That compiles fine using...

```
as -o ex.o ex.s
```

Where ex.s is the assembly source file.

But during linking...

```
ld -o ex.exe ex.o
```

It gives the error...

```
ex.o:fake:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to 'execlp'
```

So I tried to make it an extern putting...

```
.extern _execlp
```

...above where definition is (the comment).

Meanwhile I had a .c file with this code (which originally generated the ex.s file (using gcc -S -m32 -o ex.s ex.c))...

```
#include <process.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   execlp("cmd.exe", 0);
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled with...

```
gcc -o exc.exe exc.c
```

Where exc.c is the c file. It compiles and runs with the desired functionality...
So I used Dependency Walker to find the DLL's used by exc.exe and it found that kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll, and msvcrt.dll were being used. msvcrt is important because it is the c runtime library (which contains execlp).
So I tried to link ex.o like so...

```
ld -lkernel32 -lndtll -lmsvcrt -o ex.exe ex.o
```

...with

```
.extern _execlp
```

...defined within the source file (ex.s) where the comment is.

It generated the very same linking error as above...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting the `-l` switches after the object. Some versions of `ld` are known to be picky. Also try to remove the underscore, some versions add that automatically. Update: Actually you need to use `__execlp` with 2 underscores so not remove but add one more :)

Comment: The switch locations don't help. The legacy function of execlp is fine with the underscore, and even if it didn't recognize the underscore as a gas thing (which it is) it would still call _execlp which is identical in parameters and functionality. And the underscores are just the way baby likes it (gas), so I won't fool around with that. Still stuck....

Comment: I have tested, you need 2 underscores. At least that's the only version in my msvcrt.

Comment: Changed to two underscores before execlp (__execlp), still no joy. Edit : "it would still call [execlp]". Sorry.

Comment: __execv works just fine...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Also note you pass the arguments wrong. It works fine here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use 2 underscores and list the libraries after the object file.
Also, you pass the arguments wrong. This works for me:

```
    .globl _main
_main:
    push  %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    pushl $0x00657865
    pushl $0x2e646d63
    pushl $0
    lea 4(%esp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    call  __execlp
```

Assembled with: `as -o ex.o ex.s`

Linked with: `ld -o ex.exe ex.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt`